# Is there a resolution for this conflict between the material design support library and the gms:wallet library over the field "rippleColor"?

Tags: android, gradle, material-design, android-pay

In my project, when I try and add the latest design support library I get this error which appears to be in conflict with the wallet library:

```
D:\Android Stuff\ReleaseMEdia\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-wallet\8.1.0\res\values\wallet_colors.xml
Error:(2) Attribute "rippleColor" has already been defined
```

Here is the list of all my gradle dependencies below:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:8.1.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.8.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.+'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.1'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:5.1.2'
compile 'com.readystatesoftware.systembartint:systembartint:1.0.3'
compile 'com.balysv:material-ripple:0.9.0-SNAPSHOT@aar'
compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
compile 'com.jpardogo.materialtabstrip:library:1.0.6'
compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.19.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.1'
compile 'com.github.gabrielemariotti.cards:cardslib-core:2.0.1'
compile 'com.github.gabrielemariotti.cards:cardslib-cards:2.0.1'
compile 'com.github.gabrielemariotti.cards:cardslib-recyclerview:2.0.1'
compile 'se.emilsjolander:stickylistheaders:2.1.5'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:23.1.0'
compile 'com.nispok:snackbar:2.11.+'
compile 'com.uwetrottmann:trakt-java:4.3.1'
compile 'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:23.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
compile 'jp.wasabeef:picasso-transformations:1.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
```

Everything syncs fine until I add the design library at the bottom, then I am presented with this message when trying to sync gradle.

I've seen a few other people online with this issue but it doesn't look like anyone has a resolution yet. Can anyone provide any insight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this has nothing to do with wallet, but instead is an issue with the version of `com.balysv:material-ripple` you are using as per [this issue](https://github.com/balysv/material-ripple/issues/31).

The [library's Github page](https://github.com/balysv/material-ripple) shows that the latest version (which includes the above fix) is:

```
compile 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'
```

Comment: This fixed it for me. Not sure why wallet is mentioned in the error message, which I assume is why everyone with this issue is having a hard time fixing it thinking wallet is the problem. Thanks!